# re-create a nested if statement in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am trying to re-create a nested if statement that I created in Excel within a crystal report formula.  I have attempted to create the formula on my own and thought I had it figured out until I looked at the raw data and saw the calculations were off between Crystal and Excel although the raw data was exactly the same. I have checked the boards here and other sites and cannot find a solution that a beginner such as myself can follow.  What I am trying to do is adjust the scoring calculation of a formula based on specific questions.  Two of my questions have to be scored differently than the other questions in the data.

Here is what I have in excel:

```
=IF(T4="How many calls have you taken on this product since your     
 trainin",6,IF(T4="Did you experience any problems that your training did 
 not prepa",IF(U4=1,0,6),(7-U4)))
```

Here is what I have come up with in Crystal:

```
if {Command.Question_PK} = "55D0D569-7653-4553-B9C5-F858C5D318F9" Then 6
Else if {Command.Question_PK} = "15948F36-E536-4C11-834A-BB5035754024" 
then if {Command.answer} = 1 Then 0 Else 6
Else 7 - {Command.answer}
```

Looking at the data sets, it appears that Crystal is not performing the first if statement which basically is to auto-adjust the scoring for that specific question to 6 regardless of what answer respondents gave.

How can I get my calculations to match what I get in Excel when the data is exactly the same?

Comment: taking out `excel` tag as question is not related to fixing an issue formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how you have implemented your inputs. So I just wrote exact same algorithm what you have in Excel to C#. If you create console application in Visual Studio and run this you can see how it works.

```
using System;

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int result = 0;
    int U4;
    string T4;
    string statement1 = "How many calls have you taken on this product since your trainin?";
    string statement2 = "Did you experience any problems that your training did not prepa";

    Console.WriteLine("Please type value of T4");
    T4 = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Please type value of U4");
    U4 = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if (T4 == statement1)
    {
        result = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        if(T4 == statement2)
        {
            if (U4 == 1)
            {
                result = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                result = 6;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = 7 - U4;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("result is : "+result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew. I was able to incorporate the way you broke down the code into my own formula and located and resolved the issue.  Thank you again.